# Extract data from NSURLResponse

Tags: ios

I have this sweet method that authenticates a user, however I can't figure out how to get the status code of the request. I can clearly see it exists when I do `NSLog(@"%@", response);`, but I can't find any way to pull it out of that. Is there a method or do I have to parse it myself somehow?

```
- (BOOL)authenticateUserWithEmail:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                         @"%@/users/sign_in.json?user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@&user[remember_me]=true",
                                         LURL,
                                         email,
                                         password]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] );
    NSLog(@"Response Meta: %@", response);
    return (error == NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSInteger statusCode = [HTTPResponse statusCode];
```

Comment: That looks like what I need, can you explain this line `NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;`

Comment: Basically you tell the system to regard response as being of the type NSHTTPURLResponse. Since NSHTTPURLResponse inherts from NSURLResponse this is possible.
Additional NSHTTPURLResponse statusCode method.

Comment: That's brilliant, I tried to convert to `NSHTTPURLResponse` but I got an error. Thanks!

Comment: I see two things that are missing from you code, setting types for NSURL and NSMutableURLRequest. I have updated the code in your question

Comment: Thanks ya I had those at iVars, not good for new readers. Will approve :)